# dirGC = new InitialDirContext(environment); is returning null for specific credentials. I have the userid's in ldapproperties.properties

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap

`dirGC = new InitialDirContext(environment);`

is returning `null` for specific credentials. I have the user-id's in `ldapproperties.properties`. What would be the problem?

Comment: First suggestion would be to try with an alternate LDAP browser with user credentail in question try with softerra ldap browser or jxplorer .

Comment: Try to capture the exception i m sure there should be one for a reason

Comment: Error while getting user :: user@client.com[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@847fc71